# How do I save a specific line of command output as a variable on Windows?

Tags: batch-file

Consider this .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Owner: Jeremy.Coulson
ECHO Food: Ham sandwiches
ECHO Drink: Lemonade
```

Consider this second .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('source.bat') do SET OUTPUT=%%a
echo %output%
```

The result of running the second .bat file is:

```
Drink: Lemonade
```

Clearly, what I'm doing here is only getting the last thing output by source.bat.  What if instead, I wanted to specify which line to retrieve as the variable?  What if, for example, I want to retrieve only whatever is on the "Food" line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get the line containing a specific word, pipe (`|`) the output into `find` (remove the `/I` from `find` to do a case-sensitive search):

   ```
   for /F "delims=" %%L in ('call source.bat ^| find /I "Food"') do (
       set OUTPUT=%%L
       REM goto :CONTINUE
   )
   :CONTINUE
   ```

   If there could be multiple matches, you need to decide: if you want the first match, remove the `REM` in front of `goto`; if you want the last, leave it.
2. To get a certain line number, simply specify the `skip` option of `for /F`:

   ```
   set "NUMBER=4"
   set /A "SKIP=NUMBER-1"
   if %SKIP% leq 0 set "SKIP=" else set "SKIP=skip=%SKIP% "
   for /F "%SKIP%delims=" %%L in ('call source.bat') do (
       set OUTPUT=%%L
       goto :CONTINUE
   )
   :CONTINUE
   ```

   `SKIP` will contain `skip=3` in the above example (with a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, so `for /F` receives `"skip=3 delims="`). The `if` clause ensures that `SKIP` is empty in case `0` or less numbers are specified to be skipped, because `for /F` throws a syntax error in case `skip=0` is given.

Comment: In this case, I only expect one match, but it's awesome to see what to do when I expect multiple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use FIND instead.

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('find /I "Drink:" ^<source.txt') do SET OUTPUT=%%a
echo %output%
```